# Spring + Hibernate : a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, dao

In my application, which uses Spring and Hibernate, I parse a CSV file and populate the db by calling `handleRow()` every time a record is read from the CSV file.

My domain model:

> 'Family' has many 'SubFamily'
>
> 'SubFamily' has many 'Locus'
>
> a 'Locus' belongs to a 'Species'

`Family <-> SubFamily <-> Locus` are all bi-directional mappings.

Code:

```
public void handleRow(Family dummyFamily, SubFamily dummySubFamily, Locus dummyLocus) {
  //Service method which access DAO layers
  CommonService serv = ctx.getCommonService();

  boolean newFamily=false;
  Family family=serv.getFamilyByFamilyId(dummyFamily.getFamilyId());
  if(family==null){
    newFamily=true;
    family=new Family();
    family.setFamilyId(dummyFamily.getFamilyId());
    family.setFamilyIPRId(dummyFamily.getFamilyIPRId());
    family.setFamilyName(dummyFamily.getFamilyName());
    family.setFamilyPattern(dummyFamily.getFamilyPattern());
    family.setRifID(dummyFamily.getRifID());
  }

  SubFamily subFamily = family.getSubFamilyBySubFamilyId( dummySubFamily.getSubFamilyId() );
  if(subFamily==null){   
    subFamily=new SubFamily();
    subFamily.setRifID(dummySubFamily.getRifID());   
    subFamily.setSubFamilyId(dummySubFamily.getSubFamilyId());
    subFamily.setSubFamilyIPRId(dummySubFamily.getSubFamilyIPRId());
    subFamily.setSubFamilyName(dummySubFamily.getSubFamilyName());
    subFamily.setSubFamilyPattern(dummySubFamily.getSubFamilyPattern());

    family.addSubFamily(subFamily);
  }

  //use the save reference, to update from GFF handler
  Locus locus = dummyLocus;

  subFamily.addLocus(locus);

  assignSpecies(serv,locus);
  //Persist object
  if(newFamily){
    serv.createFamily(family);
  } else {
    serv.updateFamily(family);
  }
}
```

a Species is assigned to a Locus using following method, which simply accesses the DAO layer:

```
private void assignSpecies (CommonService serv, Locus locus) {
  String locusId = locus.getLocusId();
  String speciesId = CommonUtils.getLocusSpecies(locusId, ctx.getSpeciesList()).getSpeciesId();
  //Simply get Species object from DAO
  Species sp = serv.getSpeciesBySpeciesId(speciesId);
  locus.setSpecies(sp);  
}
```

Hibernate gives following error:

```
[INFO] Starting scheduled refresh cache with period [5000ms]
Hibernate: insert into species (species_id, name) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into species (species_id, name) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into species (species_id, name) values (?, ?)
############################ROW#####################1
SubFamiyID#######RIF0005913
Hibernate: select this_.id as id1_0_, this_.family_id as family2_1_0_, this_.rif_iD as rif3_1_0_, this_.family_name as family4_1_0_, this_.family_ipr_id as family5_1_0_, this_.family_pattern as family6_1_0_ from family this_ where this_.family_id=?
Creating NEW SubFamiyID#######RIF0005913
Hibernate: select this_.id as id3_0_, this_.species_id as species2_3_0_, this_.name as name3_0_ from species this_ where this_.species_id=?
Hibernate: insert into family (family_id, rif_iD, family_name, family_ipr_id, family_pattern) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into subfamily (sub_family_id, rif_iD, sub_family_name, sub_family_ipr_id, sub_family_pattern, family_id, sub_family_index) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into locus (locus_id, refTrans_id, function, species_id, sub_family_id, sub_family_index) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: update species set species_id=?, name=? where id=?
Hibernate: update subfamily set family_id=?, sub_family_index=? where id=?
Hibernate: update locus set sub_family_id=?, sub_family_index=? where id=?
############################ROW#####################2
SubFamiyID#######RIF0005913
Hibernate: select this_.id as id1_0_, this_.family_id as family2_1_0_, this_.rif_iD as rif3_1_0_, this_.family_name as family4_1_0_, this_.family_ipr_id as family5_1_0_, this_.family_pattern as family6_1_0_ from family this_ where this_.family_id=?
Hibernate: select subfamilie0_.family_id as family7_1_, subfamilie0_.id as id1_, subfamilie0_.sub_family_index as sub8_1_, subfamilie0_.id as id0_0_, subfamilie0_.sub_family_id as sub2_0_0_, subfamilie0_.rif_iD as rif3_0_0_, subfamilie0_.sub_family_name as sub4_0_0_, subfamilie0_.sub_family_ipr_id as sub5_0_0_, subfamilie0_.sub_family_pattern as sub6_0_0_, subfamilie0_.family_id as family7_0_0_ from subfamily subfamilie0_ where subfamilie0_.family_id=?
Hibernate: select locuslist0_.sub_family_id as sub5_1_, locuslist0_.id as id1_, locuslist0_.sub_family_index as sub7_1_, locuslist0_.id as id2_0_, locuslist0_.locus_id as locus2_2_0_, locuslist0_.refTrans_id as refTrans3_2_0_, locuslist0_.function as function2_0_, locuslist0_.sub_family_id as sub5_2_0_, locuslist0_.species_id as species6_2_0_ from locus locuslist0_ where locuslist0_.sub_family_id=?
Hibernate: select species0_.id as id3_0_, species0_.species_id as species2_3_0_, species0_.name as name3_0_ from species species0_ where species0_.id=?
Hibernate: select this_.id as id1_0_, this_.family_id as family2_1_0_, this_.rif_iD as rif3_1_0_, this_.family_name as family4_1_0_, this_.family_ipr_id as family5_1_0_, this_.family_pattern as family6_1_0_ from family this_ where this_.family_id=?
Hibernate: select this_.id as id3_0_, this_.species_id as species2_3_0_, this_.name as name3_0_ from species this_ where this_.species_id=?
Exception in thread "main" [INFO] Closing Compass [compass]
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.bigg.nihonbare.common.domain.Species#1]; nested exception is org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.bigg.nihonbare.common.domain.Species#1]
Caused by: org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.bigg.nihonbare.common.domain.Species#1]
 at org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.checkUniqueness(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:590)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:284)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:223)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:89)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:70)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:507)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:499)
 at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$5.cascade(CascadingAction.java:218)
 at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:268)
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use `merge()`. The exception means that the current session is already aware of the entity you are passing. If not, check how you have overridden `hashCode()` and `equals()` - it should return different values for different entities.

Comment: is there a way to do update child entity persistance with `session.saveOrUpdate`. i have used `get()` and i need to update child entity with given ID. merge is working but just for information

Comment: It would be usefull read also this article: http://www.stevideter.com/2008/12/07/saveorupdate-versus-merge-in-hibernate/

Answer (score 13):

You can also encounter this problem if you are doing a `delete()` or `update()`. The problem is likely to occur if you build the hibernate-mapped pojo yourself, perhaps from a DTO. This pojo now has the same identifier as one that is already in the `Session`, and that causes the problem.

You now have two options. Either do what @Bozho said and first `merge()` the object. That takes care of updating. For deleting, take the object returned by `merge()` and delete it.

The other option is to first query the `Session` using the id of the object and then delete or update it.

Comment: Thanks! I had problems with deleting an entity.

Answer (score 4):

I have seen this when an Entity does not have a GeneratedValue annotation for its ID column:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved so:
On delete method:

```
    this.getHibernateTemplate().clear();

    this.getHibernateTemplate().delete(obj);

    // Esta línea realiza el "commit" del comando
    this.getHibernateTemplate().flush();
```

On update method:

```
    this.getHibernateTemplate().merge(obj);

    // Esta línea realiza el "commit" del comando
    this.getHibernateTemplate().flush();
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating an object evict() it from session after the saveOrUpdate() call, also check your hashCode implementation of the object.

Answer (score 0):

You may have created two instances of `Session`

```
Session session = factory.openSession();
```

If you have opened one session in one function and executing another function with creating another session, then this problem occurs.

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me because part of my compound key was null. Ex:

```
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Username username;
```

Username happened to be null which led to "duplicate" null primary keys, even though the id was different.