# Remove an object from session in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

How can I remove an object from hibernate session? In my code I am fetching one list from the DB and searching if the user entered data is already there in the DB. If it is there I am overwriting it. Else I am creating a new object and saving it. But the jboss shows error that there are two objects in session. As far as i guess one object is the object that iterates through the list and other is the one newly created for saving the data.

```
for(Allocation al: allocatelist){
    if(al.getDate().compareTo(dt)==0){
          al.setAllocated(gpsz);
          getManager().save(al);
          flag=1;
          break;
    {
{
```

If the above condition fails then am creating and new object and saving it. So is there any way by which I can remove this object "al"?
I don't have merger or update methods I have tried "evict()" also but its of no use.
The else block

```
 Allocation allocate = new Allocation();
allocate = filldata(allocate, dataMap,i); 
   getManager().save(allocate);   
 filldata() fills the inputs into the object.`
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288838/remove-object-from-session-in-hibernate

Comment: What's the message and stack trace of the exception?

Comment: If the Allocation object is managed by Hibernate, then there is no need for you to call "getManager().save(al);" because hibernate detects that the object is changed and it will save it.

Comment: @SajanChandran: this should be an answer rather than a comment. Make it an answer, elaborate a bit more on what save means and why you can't save an already existing attached entity, and I'll upvote it.

Comment: @SajanChandran Yes it does so. But when the condition fails hibernate does not save the object. So duplicate remains

Comment: Can u post your else block ? the place you save the new object#

Comment: Allocation allocate = new Allocation();
allocate = filldata(allocate, dataMap,i);                           getManager().save(allocate);        filldata() fills the inputs into the object.

Comment: The Allocation object you create in your else block, by any chance have the same identifier as any of the allocation object from hibernate.

Comment: Any reason why you can not use session.saveOrUpdate()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `Allocation` object is managed by Hibernate, then there is no need for you to call `getManager().save(al)`, because hibernate detects that the object is changed and it will automatically update the database.

Comment: Even if i dont save, the object remains