# Inserting the same object as property in Hibernate+Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Spring + Hibernate : a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144697/spring-hibernate-a-different-object-with-the-same-identifier-value-was-alrea)

I have the following object (simplified) as a JavaBean:

```
public class Person {
  private Integer id;
  private City cityOfBirth;
  private City city;
  // ...
}
```

And in my spring form I have 2 select combos in order to choose both cities, as follows:

```
<form:form method="post" action="" commandName="person">
City of birth: <form:select path="cityOfBirth" items="${ cities }" itemValue="id" />
City: <form:select path="city" items="${ cities }" itemValue="id" />
...
</form:form>
```

My PropertyEditor for the City class would simply call to my CityDao's get, wich is the following:

```
@Component
public class CityDaoImpl implements CityDao {
  private @Autowired HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

  public City get (Integer id) {
    return (City) hibernateTemplate.get(City.class, id);
  }
}
```

And my PersonDao would do this in order to save the instance:

```
public void save (Person person) {
  hibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate (person);
}
```

Everything works OK when I try to save a Person with 2 different cities, but when I choose the same City I obtain the following error:

```
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.project.si.models.common.City#90]
```

I've read in other posts that this happens because Hibernate Session is currently aware of the previous City obtained when the propertyEditor called `cityDao.get(id)`, so I'm supposed to use merge() somewhere, but I don't get where should I apply this..

Comment: Why do you have `path="cityOfBirth"` for City field? Is that a typo? Shouldn't that be `path="city"`?

Comment: you're correct @limc, it was a typo, i've edited my question.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that you cascade `saveOrUpdate()` operation from `Person` to `City`, and `update()` fails when object with the same id as the object to be updated is already associated with the `Session`.

I think the best solution for this problem is to remove cascading options from `city` and `cityOfBirth`.

As long as your user have to select a `City` from a list of existing cities, cascading doesn't make sense here because you don't need to cascade any changes from `Person` to `City`.

Alternatively you can use `merge()` instead of `saveOrUpdate()`:

```
public void save (Person person) {
    hibernateTemplate.merge(person); 
}
```

Comment: Removing cascade options would perfectly solve my problem, thanks!