# Which is faster, get() or merge()?

Tags: hibernate

I have an hibernate object, transformed from a DTO, to delete. Because this object is not attached to the Session I can't just delete it, it will cause a [NotUniqueObjectException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22860855/297331), so I need to either merge it, or find the equivalent object in the Session. What is faster, to do `Session.get()` or `Session.merge()`?

Even better, is there a way of deleting an object without getting the managed object from the Session first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`merge()` basically gets the object, then copies the state from the detached instance to the attached one, and applies cascades. So obviously, to get an object, `get()` is not only faster, but more appropriate.

You can get an attached instance without even querying the database by using `session.load()`, which returns an uninitialized proxy if the object isn't contained by the session yet.

Comment: Good to note that calling `delete()` with a proxy for an object that doesn't exist in the db will cause an `ObjectNotFoundException`, just like if you tried to access a property of the proxy.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/608979/297331) is a nice explanation of the difference between `get()` and `load()`.