# Hibernate throws DataIntegrityViolationException when trying to update object using merge method

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Previous `update()` method was throwing `different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session` so I changed dao to [merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144697/spring-hibernate-a-different-object-with-the-same-identifier-value-was-alrea). Now it gives `org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement`

**TeamDAOImpl**

```
public void updateTeam(Team team) {
        Team teamToUpdate = getTeam(team.getId());
        teamToUpdate.setName(team.getName());
        teamToUpdate.setRating(team.getRating());
        Set<TeamMember> teamMember = team.getTeamMembers();
        teamToUpdate.setTeamMembers(teamMember);
        getCurrentSession().merge(teamToUpdate);
    }
```

**Team entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="teams")
public class Team {


    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private Integer rating;

    private Set<TeamMember> teamMembers;

// ...
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "team_member", joinColumns =
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_Team_id", referencedColumnName= "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "FK_Member_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    public Set<TeamMember> getTeamMembers() {
        return teamMembers;
    }

    public void setTeamMembers(Set<TeamMember> teamMembers) {
        this.teamMembers = teamMembers;
    }
}
```

`Team` mas ManyToMany relationship with Team members. On SQL level it's done using tables: `teams`, `member`, `team_member`.

What constraints are violated? How to fix it?

**UPDATE:**

```
CREATE TABLE `member` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
CREATE TABLE `teams` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `rating` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FK_Organization_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_Organization_id` (`FK_Organization_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Organization_id` FOREIGN KEY (`FK_Organization_id`) REFERENCES `organization` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
CREATE TABLE `team_member` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FK_Member_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FK_Team_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Member_id` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `member` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Team_id` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `teams` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

> ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Cannot add or update a child
>   row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db`.`team_member`,
>   CONSTRAINT `FK_Member_id` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `member`
>   (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

**Data:**

[image]

**UPDATE3**

```
public Team getTeam(int id) {
        Team team = (Team) getCurrentSession().get(Team.class, id);
        return team;
    }
```

**UPDATE4**
P6Spy helped to discover error query:

```
insert into team_member (FK_Team_id, FK_Member_id) values (2, 2);
```

returning:

```
[SQL] insert into team_member (FK_Team_id, FK_Member_id) values (2, 2);
[Err] 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db`.`team_member`, CONSTRAINT `FK_Member_id` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `member` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Comment: This may be an issue with your cascade. Just to test, try not setting the team members and try setting another field (that doesn't use cascade) to see what happens.

Comment: It works fine (updates all except teamMembers) if it's not set teamMembers in `TeamDAOImpl`

Comment: Can you post the sample values you were providing while doing update() or merge..?

Comment: So you have `Team teamToUpdate = getTeam(team.getId());`, which essentially means `team` and `teamToUpdate` point to the same Team, correct? if so, try changing `Set<TeamMember> teamMember = team.getTeamMembers();` to use `teamToUpdate.getTeamMembers();`

Comment: `teamToUpdate` is another object picking changes from passed `team`. No error and no update happening after suggested changes

Comment: Nvm, I guess that was kind of a dumb suggestion, on my part haha. I essentially asked you to pull the members and just update them back. Sorry! I guess when you get the error you get, it usually means 2 objects have the same primary key. In this case, both `team` and `teamToUpdate` do and you're using both. So you just need to isolate those two more. With that said, would the `getTeamMembers()` be different for `team` and `teamToUpdate`?

Comment: Can you show what `getTeam()` does? Just for clarity?

Comment: Indeed `getTeamMembers()` on `team` and `teamToUpdate` would return different data

Comment: If you're using `team.getid()` to pull a unique row from the database and setting it to `teamUpdate`, wouldn't they have the same though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in **CONSTRAINT** definition in `team_member` table. Instead of:

```
CONSTRAINT `FK_Member_id` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `member` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Team_id` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `teams` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

It has to be

```
CONSTRAINT `FK_Member_id` FOREIGN KEY (`FK_Member_id`) REFERENCES `member` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Team_id` FOREIGN KEY (`FK_Team_id`) REFERENCES `teams` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```